# Checking the convexity of a parametric set

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|v|\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Prove that
$$
\{x\in[0,1]:\sqrt{x}+vx\leq r\}
$$
is convex.

Thank you for all kind help.

Comment: Is $v$ fixed? Or should $x$ satisfy the inequality for all $v$ with $|v|\le 1/2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x):=\sqrt x + vx$ monotonically increasing on $(0,1]$ (check $f'$).

Hence the set under question is either empty (if $r<0$) or an interval $[0,x_0]\subset[0,1]$. This implies the convexity.